# i am still not getting correct value

Tags: java, for-loop

Now loop is working but I am getting the initialized value of 'tc' back.
I want the value of total cost i.e tc here by formula - **|Y-X|*max(c,b)**

But my program is giving back initialized value of tc i.e 0.

Still after resolving the loops the answer is coming same the initialized value.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    static int max(int c, int b){
        int m;
        if(b<c){
             m=c;
        } else{
             m=b;
        }
        return m;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i, y, z, b, c, j, tc = 0;
        Scanner in= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the number of soldiers");
        int n = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the coordinates of "+ n + " soldiers");
        int X[]=new int[n];
        for (i=0;i<n;i++){
            X[i]= in.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println("Enter the numbers of bomb with soldiers");
        int B[]=new int[n];
        for (i=0;i<n;i++) {
            B[i]= in.nextInt();
        }
        //below this
        for (i = n-1; i >= 1 ; i--)
        {
            y = X[i];
            c = B[i];
            System.out.println(i);
            for (j = i-1; j >= 0; j--)
            {
                System.out.println(j);

                z = X[i];
                b = B[i];
                int m = max(c,b);
                tc += (y - z) * m;

            }
        }
        // till here

        System.out.println(tc);

    }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to replace your for loop  for (i = n; i >= 1 ; i--)

Comment: @GauravJeswani that would lead to the loop continuing until `i` overflowed to `Integer.MIN_VALUE`. I don't think that's what Cipher wants here.

Comment: @Mihir, sorry updated the comment, he need to do i-- as well

Comment: Cipher, what exactly are you trying to do? What is your formula trying to represent? As a side note, you can use `Math.max(int a, int b)` rather than creating your own `max()` method.

Comment: @MihirKekkar thnx,now loops are working but answer is still coming wrong.

Comment: @MihirKekkar Its answer of problem which my friend gave me to solve but was unsuccessful though i think i got the correct logic.

Comment: Can you edit your question with what your formula is trying to calculate in the context of the problem?

Comment: @MihirKekkar i got the image of the question. i don't know how i can post it.

Comment: There is an option in the post editing toolbar to add images with either the image file or a link to the image

Comment: @Cipher Kira, could you add the input and expected output for which you are testing the above code?